# I want to use [\alert<number>] in [ColorVerbatim] in latex

Tags: latex, tex

I can use `\alert<number>{...}` outside of `ColorVerbatim`.
When I write `\alert<number>{...}` inside of `ColorVerbatim`, the text `<number>...` is colored in red.
How can I use `\alert<number>{...}` properly inside of `ColorVerbatim`?

Comment: Hi again! Are you using beamer class? Can you post an MWE or your preamble at least? Thank you.

Comment: Can you also reference `ColorVerbatim`? I don't know this environment...

Comment: Thank you for answering again!
`\documentclass[14pt, dvipdfm, cjk]{beamer}` is at the top of my tex file, so I am using beamer class.
When you write the code in tex file,  maybe you use `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}`. But `\color` is not available in `verbatim`. If you write `\begin{ColorVerbatim} ... \end{ColorVerbatim}`, `\color` is available there.

Comment: Hi, MattAllegro. I found the solution by myself. I changed `ColorVerbatim` to `semiverbatim`. Then, `\alert<2>` and `\color{gray} {...}` in `semiverbatim` work properly.
Anyway, thank you for your cooperation!

Comment: @mmsss: Would you care writing up an answer for this question?